# Sorting values at indices by size while not losing information of structure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, for-loop

I have for example 5 arrays. In there are random numbers. Now I want to know at which index of (5,6,4) which a has the biggest value. Which the second biggest and which the third..

Do you have an idea how to do so?

```
import numpy as np
import random

a1 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a2 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a3 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a4 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a5 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)

list = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]

for i in list:
```

In the end I want to have a new array like b1 with dimension (5,6,4) that has at each index the a_i with the biggest value.. Like b1 = [[a2, a5, a3 ...], [a2, a2, a2, ..]] and b2 the second biggest.. and so on.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: use this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

Comment: But I want to compare at each index the different values a_i have at that index.. this np.argsort is sorting within the a_i..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [15]: a1=np.random.randint(0,10,(2,3,4))                                                    
In [16]: a2=np.random.randint(0,10,(2,3,4))                                                    
In [17]: a3=np.random.randint(0,10,(2,3,4))
```

Collect them into one array (on a new axis), and take the max along the new axis.

```
In [18]: aa = np.array([a1,a2,a3])                                                             
In [19]: aa                                                                                    
Out[19]: 
array([[[[6, 2, 1, 2],
         [7, 6, 5, 2],
         [0, 4, 2, 5]],

        [[9, 1, 5, 3],
         [2, 5, 0, 5],
         [2, 2, 2, 7]]],


       [[[5, 2, 7, 1],
         [7, 7, 9, 8],
         [6, 3, 2, 9]],

        [[0, 1, 2, 3],
         [0, 3, 6, 1],
         [5, 2, 7, 9]]],


       [[[1, 9, 3, 3],
         [6, 5, 7, 4],
         [8, 0, 4, 4]],

        [[8, 1, 1, 8],
         [8, 5, 4, 8],
         [3, 3, 9, 0]]]])
In [20]: np.max(aa, axis=0)                                                                    
Out[20]: 
array([[[6, 9, 7, 3],
        [7, 7, 9, 8],
        [8, 4, 4, 9]],

       [[9, 1, 5, 8],
        [8, 5, 6, 8],
        [5, 3, 9, 9]]])
```

I'll let you check the values.

`argmax` tells us which array is the largest at the 3d slot:

```
In [21]: np.argmax(aa, axis=0)                                                                 
Out[21]: 
array([[[0, 2, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 0, 2, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 2],
        [2, 0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 2, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html), this will return maximum values for each position when comparing 2 arrays, and [`numpy minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html#numpy.minimum) return minimum values.

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a2 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a3 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a4 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
a5 = np.random.rand(5,6,4)

list = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]

# collect results
max_array = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
min_array = np.random.rand(5,6,4)
for i in range(0,4,1):
    max_array = np.maximum(list[i], max_array)
    min_array = np.minimum(list[i], min_array)
```